# HTACCESS VARIABLE Regarding issue

Tags: .htaccess

I have website, in which I am making URL clean with the help of htaccess.
for example.
example.com/fathers/?n=name
open as
example.com/father/name

I am doing this with the help of below code.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^father/([^\/]+)/(\/|)$  fathers/index.php?n=$1 [QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^father/([^\/]+)(\/|)$  fathers/index.php?n=$1 [QSA]
```

My question is, how to make

```
example.com/anythinghere/?n=name
open as
example.com/anythinghere/name
```

how can I do this?

Comment: anyone? please ans

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^anythinghere/([^/]*)$ /anythinghere/?n=$1 [L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache before testing it.